# Plot a non-square matrix according to the value at that point

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have an 2 dimensional array generated randomly as:-

```
In [159]:

arr
arr
Out[159]:
array([[ 0.22415888,  0.75510844,  0.30900038,  0.88540865],
       [ 0.57742895,  0.17051546,  0.5770795 ,  0.92893646],
       [ 0.39222077,  0.84292636,  0.92571946,  0.3890262 ],
       [ 0.83965826,  0.30913694,  0.24132208,  0.85672481]])
```

I want to plot the intensity of every point according to the value at that position. For example:- 0.83965826 should show up as much darker at position (3,1) than the 0.22415888 at (0,0). I need to do it using matplotlib, seaborn or any other other python visualization tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is that what you want?

```
sns.heatmap(a, annot=True)
```

[image]

Full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[ 0.22415888,  0.75510844,  0.30900038,  0.88540865],
              [ 0.57742895,  0.17051546,  0.5770795 ,  0.92893646],
              [ 0.39222077,  0.84292636,  0.92571946,  0.3890262 ],
              [ 0.83965826,  0.30913694,  0.24132208,  0.85672481]])

sns.heatmap(a, annot=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Consumes a lot of memory and time for large matrices but then that is the nature of the problem

Comment: I suspect simple plt.imshow() would need less memory, but the appearance might be less pleasing to the eye.